# Viewpager back navigation from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app has a view pager menu and when I load an activity from the second fragment I want the app to return to the *second* fragment on pressing the back button.

However, when the back button is pressed, the app returns to the *first* fragment.  I have tried overriding the `onBackPressed` but the code doesn't seem to get called.  This is the code I use to load the activity from the fragment that I want to return to:

```
// Load the Category Detail View
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CategoryDetailActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Category category = mCategoryList.get(position);
bundle.putSerializable("category_key", mCategoryList.get(position));
intent.putExtras(bundle);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please share some code ?

Comment: share the code where you are loading the 2nd fragment using FragmentManager ?

Comment: OK, the fragment code has been added.

Comment: Please take some more time to formulate your question, it is still unclear, please share some more code ?

Comment: There is no more code involved.  I load an activity from a fragment (shown) and would like to return to that fragment (not the first fragment).

Comment: the default behavior is what you are looking for.. there is something that stops it from happening, can you share your project ?

Comment: you do not need to override anything, if you run a activity from 2nd fragment in your view pager, you shall return at the same place by default... if you want to override try to work on savedInstanceState instead

Comment: The default behaviour takes me from the loaded activity to the first tab (fragment) of the app.  I would like to return to the second tab (fragment).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76786/discussion-between-divyenduz-and-carl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the activity that holds the viewpager, you need to override `onPause` or `onSaveInstanceState` and save the position in the adapter that is currently being shown. Then you need to also override `onResume` and or `onRestoreInstanceState` and in this set the position in the viewpagers adapter to the one that was just stored.